# Git log graph into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, git, split

I need to convert a git log output into object.

I'm using the command `git log --all --graph --oneline --date-order`.

```
* 8896805 (origin/firstbranch) test(firstbranch): this is my commit on this branch
| * 5fef2da (HEAD -> testbranch, origin/another, another) refactor(another): this is a change
| * 2a34d72 refactor(another): typo
| * 683d704 refactor(another): changes
* |   0120274 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into firstbranch
|\ \
```

After that I created an array where each element of the array corresponds to a line of this output.

And with this, I would like to have an array like this :

```
[
    {
        art: "*",
        commitHash: "8896805",
        branches: ["origin/firstbranch"],
        commitString: "test(firstbranch): this is my commit on this branch"
    },
    {
        art: "| *",
        commitHash: "5fef2da",
        branches: ["testbranch", "origin/another", "another"],
        commitString: "refactor(another): this is a change"
    },
    {
        art: "| *",
        commitHash: "2a34d72",
        branches: [],
        commitString: "refactor(another): typo"
    },
    {
        art: "| *",
        commitHash: "683d704",
        branches: [],
        commitString: "refactor(another): changes"
    },
    {
        art: "* |",
        commitHash: "0120274",
        branches: [],
        commitString: "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into firstbranch"
    },
    {
        art: "|\ \",
        commitHash: "",
        branches: [],
        commitString: ""
    }
]
```

But I can't obtain this result.

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: I'm sorry but I deleted my attempts, cause I wasn't on the right approach.

Comment: @Nulji you should add it, it makes people answering more precise to address what was wrong with your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using a single regular expression, then [trimming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) each value, and finally [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) branches into an array:

```js
const input = [
  '* 8896805 (origin/firstbranch) test(firstbranch): this is my commit on this branch',
  '| * 5fef2da (HEAD -> testbranch, origin/another, another) refactor(another): this is a change',
  '| * 2a34d72 refactor(another): typo',
  '| * 683d704 refactor(another): changes',
  '* |   0120274 Merge remote-tracking branch \'origin/develop\' into firstbranch',
  '|\\ \\'
];

const result = input.map(entry => {
  let [, alt, commitHash, branches, commitString] = entry
    .match(/^([|*\s\\]+)(?:\s+([a-f0-9]+)?(?:\s+\((?:HEAD\s+->\s+)?([^)]+)\))?(?:\s+(.*))?)?$/)
    .map(value => value ? value.trim() : '');
  branches = branches ? branches.split(/\s*,\s*/) : [];
  return {alt, commitHash, branches, commitString};
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with the regex.

1. `alt` regex

   - `^\W+` - This matches all the non word character at start of string.
2. `commitHash` regex

   - `\w+` - This matches all the word characters and we select only first match
3. `branches` regex

   - `/\(.*?\)/` - This matches all the branches `( branches here )`
   - now from the matches branches we replace `(Head ->` and `()` with replace
4. `commit` regex

   - `/.*?\)|\W+/` - Replace all the character upto first `)` or all the non word characters.

```js
let str = `* 8896805 (origin/firstbranch) test(firstbranch): this is my commit on this branch
| * 5fef2da (HEAD -> testbranch, origin\/another, another) refactor(another): this is a change
| * 2a34d72 refactor(another): typo
| * 683d704 refactor(another): changes
* |   0120274 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into firstbranch
|\\ \\`

let splited = str.split('\n')

let op = splited.map(inp=>{
  let alt = "" 
  inp = inp.replace(/^\W+/,(match)=>{alt=match; return ''})
  
  let commitHash = ''
  inp = inp.replace(/\s*(\w+)\s*/,(match,g1)=>{commitHash = g1;return ''})
  let branches = ''
  inp = inp.replace(/^\s*(\(.*?\))/,(match,g1)=>{branches = g1; return ''})
  branches = branches ? branches.replace(/^\s*\(HEAD\s*->\s*|[)(]/g,'').split(/\s*,\s*/) : []
  let commit = inp.trim()
  return {alt,commitHash,branches,commit}
})

console.log(op)
```

**On Side Note:-** Please note this is not full proof. i have considered cases as per provided input but there can be many more cases

Comment: Thanks it's almost what I need. I've just a problem with your code :
The commit 2a34d72 and 683d704 of your example doesn't work cause it gives me a branch but it doesn't have it then the commit string is splitted.
If you can fix that quickly, huge thanks!

Comment: I would say it's a bit of a shame to use `match` twice just for the purpose of the ternary operator. You can do `let alt = (inp.match(/^\W+/) || [''])[0]` instead (same for others).

Comment: @Nulji i made some changes, you can see.

Comment: @Jeto yes, i have changed it replace the matched one and than proceed further, you can see the updated one